# How to Duplicate Git repository hosted on TFS 2015

Tags: git, version-control, tfs-2015

I have a Git repository hosted on Team Foundation Server 2015.

I need to leave it unchanged (in order to create new releases and do some maintenance).

And I want to create new version of the product (having a lot of branches and so on) with massive code change starting from the current state of the project.

Therefore I need to have the same Git repo alongside of given one (with all history available).

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The steps are relatively simple:

- Create a new empty repository on the TFS server. Make sure **not** to check the "Create default readme and .gitignore".
- Create a local clone of the repository you want to mirror using `git clone --mirror https://tfs/clone/url`.
- Add the new repository clone url to the local clone: `git remote add target https://tfs/clone/new/repo/url`
- Push all to the target repo: `git push target --mirror`